# SELECT from alias used in sub query

Tags: postgresql, select, subquery, alias

I define a field called a.onhold_endtime in the below code. I want to return that value as part of overall SELECT statement, but when I include it the alias a.* is not recognised. It returns an error "ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a" "

```
Select distinct 
woas.workorderid,
a.onhold_endtime,

(SELECT 
(SELECT count(*) AS work_hours
FROM   generate_series (b.onhold_starttime
                  , a.onhold_endtime - interval '1h'
                  , interval '1h') h
WHERE  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM h) < 6
AND    h::time >= '08:00'
AND    h::time <= '18:00') 
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
        timestamp 'epoch' + 
        nth_value(wos.endtime,1)  OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        /1000 * INTERVAL '1 second' as onhold_endtime from wo_status_info wos
    LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
    WHERE tmp.workorderid = woas.workorderid AND wos.statusid = 1 AND wos.nextstatusid = 2
) as a
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
        timestamp 'epoch' + 
        nth_value(wos.endtime,1)  OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        /1000 * INTERVAL '1 second' as onhold_starttime from wo_status_info wos
    LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
    WHERE 
        (wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid <> 2)
) as b ON a.workorderid = b.workorderid) AS onhold_difference1

FROM wo_assessment as tmp
LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON tmp.assessmentid = woas.assessmentid
LEFT JOIN wo_status_info wos ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
ORDER BY woas.workorderid ASC
```

Is there a way I can structure the code so I can include items using the "a" alias?

**Update with simplified code** 
I define a value called "onhold_endtime" within a subquery with an alias of "a". I would like to return the value a.onhold_endtime in my main SELECT statement

```
Select distinct 
woas.workorderid,
a.onhold_endtime,

(SELECT 
        (SELECT count(*)) 
        FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
                nth_value(wos.endtime,1)  OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
            as onhold_endtime from wo_status_info wos
            WHERE y.workorderid = woas.workorderid AND wos.statusid = 1 AND wos.nextstatusid = 2
        ) as a
        LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
                nth_value(wos.endtime,1)  OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
                as onhold_starttime from wo_status_info wos
            WHERE 
                (wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid <> 2)
        ) as b ON a.workorderid = b.workorderid) AS x

FROM wo_assessment as y
LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON y.assessmentid = woas.assessmentid
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61449/aliases-with-correlated-subqueries

Comment: Thank you, however I am struggling with the syntax. If you could provide an example with my code that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: please cut your code to some short sample with problem - I'll help you

Comment: Thanks, I have simplified the code as best I can, whilst still leaving it in a working state :)

Answer (score 0):

In short - you can use outer query alias in correlated subquery:

```
t=# select o.oid, (select o.datname||'*') from pg_database o limit 1;
  oid  | ?column?
-------+-----------
 13505 | postgres*
(1 row)
```

but can't do the opposite:

```
t=# select b.*, (select o.datname||'*') b from pg_database o limit 1;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"
LINE 1: select b.*, (select o.datname||'*') b from pg_database o lim...

            ^
```

the closest to the expected would be:

```
t=# select oid,b.* from pg_database o, LATERAL (select o.datname||'*') b limit 1;
  oid  | ?column?
-------+-----------
 13505 | postgres*
(1 row)
```